# failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt'

Tags: laravel

[image]

How to solve this error ?

> failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt'

[image]

Comment: No error in your code, This information is not enough to understand. Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are not providing a valid ca bundle file.

Try downloading [this file](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and save it as `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt`
You can read the explanation on [the Certificate Verification section of the curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html).

> libcurl performs peer SSL certificate verification by default. This is
>   done by using a CA certificate store that the SSL library can use to
>   make sure the peer's server certificate is valid.

Comment: the file should be replaced?

Comment: I'm confused, why is a cert required if a generic trash one downloaded on a random SO answer fit the bill?

Comment: any one to clarify, I download it and placed it on the folder but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to update `php.ini` file and add this

```
openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```