# Laravel : send email : error ( failed loading cafile stream)

Tags: laravel

I try to do this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488982/failed-loading-cafile-stream-c-xampp-apache-bin-curl-ca-bundle-crt)
but it didn't work :(

error:

failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt'

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

is there any other solution?

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=katty17@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Mail.php

```
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),



    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'kawtarmar17@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'hotel'),
    ],


    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),



    'username' => env('katty17@gmail.com'),

    'password' => env('password'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],



    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

php.ini

```
...

[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo ="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"

[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
openssl.cafile ="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have enabled two-step authentication for your email application, and make sure you have created an app password!
https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp

Answer (score -1):

Also you may have two or more php.ini files, make sure you specify paths of

```
curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

every of them